# Why is this index html not displaying the game on my desk top?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I found this game online and am trying to get it to run from my desktop. Is there something special that a person has to do with the URL's or images to make the file recognize were everything is running and located at. I have all of the files and .png files in one folder and on the same level.

I would think that I should see the game on the screen. It is like a left to right horizontal scroll-er with enemy ships that come out of the right side of the screen and the main ship is on the right side of the screen. (Similar to that of the old style defender game)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="game-over-overlay"></div>

    <div id="game-over">
      <h1>GAME OVER</h1>
      <button id="play-again">Play Again</button>
    </div>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="instructions">
        <div>
          move with <span class="key">arrows</span> or <span class="key">wasd</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          shoot with <span class="key">space</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="score"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="input.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sprite.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

sprite.js

```
(function() {
    function Sprite(url, pos, size, speed, frames, dir, once) {
        this.pos  = pos;
        this.size = size;
        this.speed  = typeof speed === 'number' ? speed : 0;
        this.frames = frames;
        this._index = 0;
        this.url = url;
        this.dir = dir || 'horizontal';
        this.once = once;
    };

    Sprite.prototype = {
        update: function(dt) {
            this._index += this.speed*dt;
        },

        render: function(ctx) {
            var frame;

            if(this.speed > 0) {
                var max = this.frames.length;
                var idx = Math.floor(this._index);
                frame = this.frames[idx % max];

                if(this.once && idx >= max) {
                    this.done = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
            else {
                frame = 0;
            }

            var x = this.pos[0];
            var y = this.pos[1];

            if(this.dir == 'vertical') {
                y += frame * this.size[1];
            }
            else {
                x += frame * this.size[0];
            }

            ctx.drawImage(resources.get(this.url),
                          x, y,
                          this.size[0], this.size[1],
                          0, 0,
                          this.size[0], this.size[1]);
        }
    };

    window.Sprite = Sprite;
```

resources.js

```
(function() {
    var resourceCache = {};
    var loading = [];
    var readyCallbacks = [];

    // Load an image url or an array of image urls
    function load(urlOrArr) {
        if(urlOrArr instanceof Array) {
            urlOrArr.forEach(function(url) {
                _load(url);
            });
        }
        else {
            _load(urlOrArr);
        }
    }

    function _load(url) {
        if(resourceCache[url]) {
            return resourceCache[url];
        }
        else {
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                resourceCache[url] = img;

                if(isReady()) {
                    readyCallbacks.forEach(function(func) { func(); });
                }
            };
            resourceCache[url] = false;
            img.src = url;
        }
    }

    function get(url) {
        return resourceCache[url];
    }

    function isReady() {
        var ready = true;
        for(var k in resourceCache) {
            if(resourceCache.hasOwnProperty(k) &&
               !resourceCache[k]) {
                ready = false;
            }
        }
        return ready;
    }

    function onReady(func) {
        readyCallbacks.push(func);
    }

    window.resources = { 
        load: load,
        get: get,
        onReady: onReady,
        isReady: isReady
    };
```

input.js

```
(function() {
    var pressedKeys = {};

    function setKey(event, status) {
        var code = event.keyCode;
        var key;

        switch(code) {
        case 32:
            key = 'SPACE'; break;
        case 37:
            key = 'LEFT'; break;
        case 38:
            key = 'UP'; break;
        case 39:
            key = 'RIGHT'; break;
        case 40:
            key = 'DOWN'; break;
        default:
            key = String.fromCharCode(code);
        }

        pressedKeys[key] = status;
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        setKey(e, true);
    });

    document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
        setKey(e, false);
    });

    window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
        pressedKeys = {};
    });

    window.input = {
        isDown: function(key) {
            return pressedKeys[key.toUpperCase()];
        }
    };
```

apps.js

```
// A cross-browser requestAnimationFrame
// See https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/
var requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return window.requestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function(callback){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();

// Create the canvas
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width  = 512;
canvas.height = 480;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

// The main game loop
var lastTime;
function main() {
    var now = Date.now();
    var dt = (now - lastTime) / 1000.0;

    update(dt);
    render();

    lastTime = now;
    requestAnimFrame(main);
};

function init() {
    terrainPattern = ctx.createPattern(resources.get('terrain.png'), 'repeat');

    document.getElementById('play-again').addEventListener('click', function() {
        reset();
    });

    reset();
    lastTime = Date.now();
    main();
}

resources.load([
    'sprites.png',
    'terrain.png'
]);
resources.onReady(init);

// Game state
var player = {
    pos: [0, 0],
    sprite: new Sprite('sprites.png', [0, 0], [39, 39], 16, [0, 1])
};

var bullets = [];
var enemies = [];
var explosions = [];

var lastFire = Date.now();
var gameTime = 0;
var isGameOver;
var terrainPattern;

var score = 0;
var scoreEl = document.getElementById('score');

// Speed in pixels per second
var playerSpeed = 200;
var bulletSpeed = 500;
var enemySpeed = 100;

// Update game objects
function update(dt) {
    gameTime += dt;

    handleInput(dt);
    updateEntities(dt);

    // It gets harder over time by adding enemies using this
    // equation: 1-.993^gameTime
    if(Math.random() < 1 - Math.pow(.993, gameTime)) {
        enemies.push({
            pos: [canvas.width,
                  Math.random() * (canvas.height - 39)],
            sprite: new Sprite('sprites.png', [0, 78], [80, 39],
                               6, [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1])
        });
    }

    checkCollisions();

    scoreEl.innerHTML = score;
};

function handleInput(dt) {
    if(input.isDown('DOWN') || input.isDown('s')) {
        player.pos[1] += playerSpeed * dt;
    }

    if(input.isDown('UP') || input.isDown('w')) {
        player.pos[1] -= playerSpeed * dt;
    }

    if(input.isDown('LEFT') || input.isDown('a')) {
        player.pos[0] -= playerSpeed * dt;
    }

    if(input.isDown('RIGHT') || input.isDown('d')) {
        player.pos[0] += playerSpeed * dt;
    }

    if(input.isDown('SPACE') && !isGameOver && Date.now() - lastFire > 100) {
        var x = player.pos[0] + player.sprite.size[0] / 2;
        var y = player.pos[1] + player.sprite.size[1] / 2;

        bullets.push({ pos: [x, y],
                       dir: 'forward',
                       sprite: new Sprite('sprites.png', [0, 39], [18, 8]) });
        bullets.push({ pos: [x, y],
                       dir: 'up',
                       sprite: new Sprite('sprites.png', [0, 50], [9, 5]) });
        bullets.push({ pos: [x, y],
                       dir: 'down',
                       sprite: new Sprite('sprites.png', [0, 60], [9, 5]) });

        lastFire = Date.now();
    }
}

function updateEntities(dt) {
    // Update the player sprite animation
    player.sprite.update(dt);

    // Update all the bullets
    for(var i=0; i<bullets.length; i++) {
        var bullet = bullets[i];

        switch(bullet.dir) {
        case 'up': bullet.pos[1] -= bulletSpeed * dt; break;
        case 'down': bullet.pos[1] += bulletSpeed * dt; break;
        default:
            bullet.pos[0] += bulletSpeed * dt;
        }

        // Remove the bullet if it goes offscreen
        if(bullet.pos[1] < 0 || bullet.pos[1] > canvas.height ||
           bullet.pos[0] > canvas.width) {
            bullets.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    // Update all the enemies
    for(var i=0; i<enemies.length; i++) {
        enemies[i].pos[0] -= enemySpeed * dt;
        enemies[i].sprite.update(dt);

        // Remove if offscreen
        if(enemies[i].pos[0] + enemies[i].sprite.size[0] < 0) {
            enemies.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }

    // Update all the explosions
    for(var i=0; i<explosions.length; i++) {
        explosions[i].sprite.update(dt);

        // Remove if animation is done
        if(explosions[i].sprite.done) {
            explosions.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
        }
    }
}

// Collisions

function collides(x, y, r, b, x2, y2, r2, b2) {
    return !(r <= x2 || x > r2 ||
             b <= y2 || y > b2);
}

function boxCollides(pos, size, pos2, size2) {
    return collides(pos[0], pos[1],
                    pos[0] + size[0], pos[1] + size[1],
                    pos2[0], pos2[1],
                    pos2[0] + size2[0], pos2[1] + size2[1]);
}

function checkCollisions() {
    checkPlayerBounds();

    // Run collision detection for all enemies and bullets
    for(var i=0; i<enemies.length; i++) {
        var pos = enemies[i].pos;
        var size = enemies[i].sprite.size;

        for(var j=0; j<bullets.length; j++) {
            var pos2 = bullets[j].pos;
            var size2 = bullets[j].sprite.size;

            if(boxCollides(pos, size, pos2, size2)) {
                // Remove the enemy
                enemies.splice(i, 1);
                i--;

                // Add score
                score += 100;

                // Add an explosion
                explosions.push({
                    pos: pos,
                    sprite: new Sprite('sprites.png',
                                       [0, 117],
                                       [39, 39],
                                       16,
                                       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12],
                                       null,
                                       true)
                });

                // Remove the bullet and stop this iteration
                bullets.splice(j, 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        if(boxCollides(pos, size, player.pos, player.sprite.size)) {
            gameOver();
        }
    }
}

function checkPlayerBounds() {
    // Check bounds
    if(player.pos[0] < 0) {
        player.pos[0] = 0;
    }
    else if(player.pos[0] > canvas.width - player.sprite.size[0]) {
        player.pos[0] = canvas.width - player.sprite.size[0];
    }

    if(player.pos[1] < 0) {
        player.pos[1] = 0;
    }
    else if(player.pos[1] > canvas.height - player.sprite.size[1]) {
        player.pos[1] = canvas.height - player.sprite.size[1];
    }
}

// Draw everything
function render() {
    ctx.fillStyle = terrainPattern;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // Render the player if the game isn't over
    if(!isGameOver) {
        renderEntity(player);
    }

    renderEntities(bullets);
    renderEntities(enemies);
    renderEntities(explosions);
};

function renderEntities(list) {
    for(var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
        renderEntity(list[i]);
    }    
}

function renderEntity(entity) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(entity.pos[0], entity.pos[1]);
    entity.sprite.render(ctx);
    ctx.restore();
}

// Game over
function gameOver() {
    document.getElementById('game-over').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('game-over-overlay').style.display = 'block';
    isGameOver = true;
}

// Reset game to original state
function reset() {
    document.getElementById('game-over').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('game-over-overlay').style.display = 'none';
    isGameOver = false;
    gameTime = 0;
    score = 0;

    enemies = [];
    bullets = [];

    player.pos = [50, canvas.height / 2];
```

app.css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #151515;
}

canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 512px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 2em;
}

#instructions {
    float: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #757575;
}

#score {
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2em;
}

.key {
    color: #aaffdd;
}

#game-over, #game-over-overlay {
    margin: auto;
    width: 512px;
    height: 480px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: none;
}

#game-over-overlay {
    background-color: black;
    opacity: .5;
}

#game-over {
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
}

#game-over h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

#game-over button {
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is the original game link

```
  http://jlongster.com/Making-Sprite-based-Games-with-Canvas
```

If someone could put up a fiddle to see why it is not working it would be most appreciated.

**Errors from the console**

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input resources.js:61
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input input.js:43
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input sprite.js:54
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input app.js:302
```

Comment: I would not expect anyone but me to debug the problem. And the first thing that I would do is check the browser error console. I am sure you will see HTML5 canvas security errors.

Comment: Your HTML looks for "app.css" then you pasted "apps.css". Check the console for errors.

Comment: I checked that and everything was ok in the index.html file. It was looking for the correct file.

Comment: Well, I got it fixed I was missing }()); the namespace closing on the end of all of the .js files.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this on a webserver? The way that you phrased it makes me think you you downloaded those files and just double-clicked index.html.

You need to download something like https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html and start the Apache service up, then put your files in the /xampp/htdocs/ folder... then goto

```
http://localhost/index.html
```

to get it to load.

Comment: That is how i am doing it. That is how I would prefer to test it by just running it off of my desktop.